# Cannot find class in classpath: Open_MRS_POM.Open_MRS_Engine

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.13.0
Cannot find class in classpath
```

Tried almost everything mentioned in the previous blogs. Cleaned the project, updated Maven project, restarted Eclipse etc, Edited the TestNG XML file with the package name.class name as mentioned. But still the issue persists.

```
org.testng.TestNGException:
```

Comment: Please post your TestNG.xml file here!?

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the test from Maven command line interface.
 1. Go to the project path.
 2. Enter the command "mvn clean install". 
I have had this several times and this was the solution.
Note: Maven needs to be installed on PC and its environment variables have to be set.